# How to change window form title font size and font family?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window application that has a window form. I have to change this window form header text (Font Size and Font family etc). I am unable to do this. I am attaching an image for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via the Style Libraries in the [Custom Border Form](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/) project on CodePlex.

There are currently three skins available: Longhorn, Vista, and WMP. There are some [demo usages](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Demo/DemoForm.cs) as well on the site.

Alternatively there is also [WinForms SkinFramework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61485/Winforms-SkinFramework) available on CodeProject.

The problem lies in the fact that WinForms is a managed wrapper around the native Windows UI elements. So the font and other styling is ultimately controlled via the Operating System theme (Aero in this case).