# How to change the font size of the form title?

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Windows Forms application, I have a form named `Brand.cs`.

In some cases, I must change the font size of the form title. I found it quite hard to change the size of the form title.

How to change the font size of the form title easily?

Comment: What do you mean changing the size of the form name? Are you talking about the title in the title bar? This is a setting which is controlled by the operating system. If you mean something else may provide a screenshot before/after of what you want to achieve.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23276375/how-to-change-window-form-title-font-size-and-font-family

Comment: @Amit: You are right, but you can't close a question as a duplicate of a question that wasn't accepted or doesn't have any up-votes.

Comment: @patrick-hofman: #1 I did not mark it for closing, #2 It already had a down-vote when I came here #3 simple google search lands bunch of SO questions like the one I linked above, which means this question was asked without doing any research #4 lot of new users on SO do not accept or up-vote answers, no wonder if your answer below gets ignored too.. :)

Comment: @Amit : I know. It was just to let you know, since you might wonder why this question doesn't get closed. And I don't like the other answer, so that's why I answered. And the reputation isn't so interesting as it seems ;)

Comment: This would be useful when scaling the app to work right on a 4k monitor.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that without changing the Windows theme (which you can programmatically) or [custom-paint the title bar](http://customerborderform.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Painting%20NonClient%20Area&referringTitle=Home).

I do wonder if you are on the right track. There is a reason that there is a default style, and they have made it virtually impossible to change it on purpose. You should consider what this will do for the user experience of you application.

If you do intend to give your form a more custom look, I would advise to use WPF, which is more suitable for this kind of scenarios.